# Javascript Jquery Popup Contact Form - Auto Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I am trying to get a jquery popup contact form to load automatically when the page opens. Currently it only opens when you click the link but I want it to load automatically. I am new to this. Am I looking in the right location of my code? How do I create onLoad?  -Thanks in advance!

```
<script>$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$('#myModal').reveal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code too?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood by looking at your code is, that your code is incomplete.

Your HTML should be similar to

```
<div id="revealModal" class="reveal-modal">
  {your_contact_content_goes_here}
</div>
```

And have a dummy `a` tag in your HTML page and it should be

```
<a href="#" id="revealModalTrigger" data-reveal-id="revealModal" style="visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

Now your JS should be

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#revealModal").reveal();
        jQuery("#revealModalTrigger").trigger( "click" );
    });
</script>
```

For further understanding just refer [Reveal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin).

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your jQuery to start executing after the page is fully loaded, you can use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
// insert code here
// trigger event here. 
});
</script>
```

The `document ready` event executes when the `HTML is loaded and the DOM is ready`, even if all the images on your page haven’t loaded yet.

The `window load` event executes later when the page is fully loaded, including all images and other objects.

Hope this will help you.!

Comment: `trigger event` just like `Faizul Hasan` said.